# Detecting if image (in console) is looked at through getter

Tags: javascript, image, console, getter

I would like to make a small script that checks if the console is open. I looked at many posts and most say that it is not possible anymore. However, I found one that said this:

> ... I added a small script that would redirect the player to a 404 if they opened devtools.
> To accomplish this, I created an Image with a getter, which was logged to console. If console was opened, the getter would be triggered, and the user would be 404'd.

Is this possible? If it is, then how do I use a getter to accomplish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var element = new Image()
Object.defineProperty(element, 'id', {
  get() {
    alert('Hello')
  }
})
console.log(element)
```

Comment: works with other elements also `document.createElement(p)`

Comment: fyi, this don't work for me in chrome anymore